# Crop Recorded Video Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avvideocomposition

I am trying to crop a video frame. I have recorded the video using `AVFoundation` framework. I need to crop the snapped image and recorded video into a square shape. I have done it for the `UIImage` which worked, and now I am trying to crop the video.

> ```
> - (UIImage *)squareImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
>   // Cropping UIImage is working fine.
>   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectMake(0,0, image.size.width, image.size.width));
>   UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
>   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
>   return result;
> }
> ```

I tried to crop the video but it resulted in changing the whole video frame without cropping, and it looks stretched.

> ```
> _writer = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:url fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:nil];
> NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                           AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
>                           [NSNumber numberWithInt: 320], AVVideoWidthKey,
>                           [NSNumber numberWithInt: 320], AVVideoHeightKey,
>                           nil];
> _videoInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:settings];
> [_writer addInput:_videoInput];
> ```

Can anybody help me to solve this cropping issue for video? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I have found solution for my issue. i have answered for my question below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is my code which is used to crop video.we need to set `AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey` which contains `AVVideoCleanApertureKey` key for video settings.

I Reffered : [How to crop video into square iOS with AVAssetWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882871/how-to-crop-video-into-square-ios-with-avassetwriter?rq=1)

> ```
> NSDictionary *videoCleanApertureSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:cx], AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey,
>                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:cx], AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey,
>                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey,
>                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey,
>                                             nil];
> NSDictionary *videoAspectRatioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], AVVideoPixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacingKey,
>                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],AVVideoPixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacingKey,
>                                           nil];
> NSDictionary *codecSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:960000], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
>                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,
>                                videoCleanApertureSettings, AVVideoCleanApertureKey,
>                                //videoAspectRatioSettings, AVVideoPixelAspectRatioKey,
>                                //AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main30, AVVideoProfileLevelKey,
>                                nil];
> NSString *targetDevice = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
> NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,AVVideoScalingModeKey,
>                                AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
>                                codecSettings,AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
>                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:cx], AVVideoWidthKey,
>                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:cx], AVVideoHeightKey,
>                                nil];
> _videoInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
> ```